# How to return a value into a variable in Java

Tags: java

If I want to put all the values from the myNum[x] into a varible

```
int myNum[] = {1, 2, 22, 89, 56, 45};
int num = myNum.length;
int greater ;
for (int x = 0 ; x < num ; x++)
if (myNum[x] > 10) {
System.out.print(greater+"are than 10");
  }
```

P.S. Still trying to find my feet in Java Programming

Comment: Have another array of size `num` and copy the values to the array that satisfies the condition.

Comment: We are not clear with the purpose of this question. An array contains a list of values. How can you store all of them in a single variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to assign myNum[x] to greater.

```
  if (myNum[x] > 10) {
            greater=myNum[x];
            System.out.print(greater+"are than 10");
      }
```

If your requirement is keep all `values >10`, then greater should be either `array/list`.  Here is example for list.

```
List<Integer> greater= new ArrayList<Integer>();

     if (myNum[x] > 10) {
                    greater.add(myNum[x]);
                    System.out.print(myNum[x]+"are than 10");
              }
```

EDIT

```
  if (myNum[x] > 10) {
            greater++;
            System.out.print(greater+"are than 10");
      }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just get overwritten if there was more than value greater than 10?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm looking for is to return a single integer for all values greater than 10.. I.e there are 5 numbers greater than 10.

Comment: increment greater variable, at the end of loop you will get the number. See updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
int myNum[] = {1, 2, 22, 89, 56, 45};
int num = myNum.length;
int greater;
for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    if (myNum[x] > 10) {
        greater = myNum[x];
        System.out.print(greater + "are than 10");
    }
}
```

You have a handful of redundant variables, however. The code can be simplified:

```
int myNum[] = {1, 2, 22, 89, 56, 45};
for (int x = 0; x < myNum.length; x++) {
    if (myNum[x] > 10) {
        System.out.print(myNum[x] + "are than 10");
    }
}
```

.... Or did you want to actually store each of those individual values?

```
int myNum[] = {1, 2, 22, 89, 56, 45};
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int x = 0; x < myNum.length; x++) {
    if (myNum[x] > 10) {
        System.out.print(myNum[x] + "are than 10");
        values.add(myNum[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int myNum[] = {1, 2, 22, 89, 56, 45};
for (int x = 0 ; x < myNum.length; x++)
    if (myNum[x] > 10) {
        System.out.print(myNum[x] + " are than 10");    
    }
```

Simplified version of your code,

So, I ve removed an extra `int num = myNum.length;` and `int greater ;`

Let me know if it is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to list all the numbers that are greater then 10 on one line so output
22, 89, 56, 45 are grater then 10? (since you use are)

If you are one simple solution would be to initialize a string greater instead before the for loop and then just concatenate it in the for loop then print it.

so

```
int myNum[] = {1, 2, 22, 89, 56, 45};
int num = myNum.length;
string greater = ""
for (int x = 0 ; x < num ; x++)
   if (myNum[x] > 10) {
    greater = greater + myNum[x]  # and what ever format you want between numbers
   }
}
System.out.print(greater+"are than 10");
```

There are fancier solutions with stringbuilder or vectors but this is the most basic.